Conditional Props - Props that depend on other optional Props with default value
I want to set type of one prop, based on value of another OPTIONAL prop.
submitOnlyChangedValues is optional prop, it can be true or false or not provided in which case it's behavior should be as if it's true.
based on it, onSubmit prop's type should be compile time ready. I thought I could do something like the following to achieve this:
    interface PropTrue<T> {
        submitOnlyChangedValues: true
        onSubmit: (values: Partial<T>) => Promise<void> | void;
    }
    
    interface PropFalse<T> {
        submitOnlyChangedValues: false
        onSubmit: (values: T) => Promise<void> | void;
    }
    
    interface PropNotGiven<T> {
        submitOnlyChangedValues?: boolean
        onSubmit: (values: Partial<T>) => Promise<void> | void;
    }
    
    interface CommonProps<T> {
        initialValues: T
    }
    
    type Props<T> = CommonProps<T> & (
        | PropTrue<T>
        | PropFalse<T>
        | PropNotGiven<T>
    )
    
    class Driver<T> {
        constructor({submitOnlyChangedValues, onSubmit}: Props<T>) {}
    }
    
    const trueProp = new Driver<{name: string}>({
        initialValues: {name: "nick"},
        submitOnlyChangedValues: true,
        onSubmit: (values) => console.log(values.name)
    })

// ***********************************************************************************
    const falseProp = new Driver<{name: string}>({
        initialValues: {name: "nick"},
        submitOnlyChangedValues: false,
        onSubmit: (values) => console.log(values.name) // **values** is of type **any** <<<<<<
    })
// ***********************************************************************************
    
    const noProp = new Driver<{name: string}>({
        initialValues: {name: "nick"},
        onSubmit: (values) => console.log(values.name)
    })
    

However, sending that prop as true or not sending is working fine. sending it as false is giving the values "any" type. What can I do here?
P.s. in my Driver class, how can I also call onSubmit with proper typing given the other prop is true or false or undefined?

I guess I was overcomplicating it.
interface PropTrue<T> {
    submitOnlyChangedValues?: true
    onSubmit: (values: Partial<T>) => Promise<void> | void;
}

interface PropFalse<T> {
    submitOnlyChangedValues: false
    onSubmit: (values: T) => Promise<void> | void;
}

interface CommonProps<T> {
    initialValues: T
}

type Props<T> = CommonProps<T> & (
    | PropTrue<T>
    | PropFalse<T>
)

class Driver<T> {
    constructor({submitOnlyChangedValues, onSubmit}: Props<T>) {}
}

const trueProp = new Driver<{name: string}>({
    initialValues: {name: "nick"},
    submitOnlyChangedValues: true,
    onSubmit: (values) => console.log(values.name)
})

const falseProp = new Driver<{name: string}>({
    initialValues: {name: "nick"},
    submitOnlyChangedValues: false,
    onSubmit: (values) => console.log(values.name)
})

const noProp = new Driver<{name: string}>({
    initialValues: {name: "nick"},
    onSubmit: (values) => console.log(values.name)
})


